# How to set different font family based on text language?

Tags: css, fonts

I Developed one Newspaper portal in WordPress. I am using **Two languages in this portal Tamil(site language) and English**.

Now I am using **Nova Sans Tamil font for Tamil language font**
and **Roboto font For English**

In Headings and Menus I can easily handle this problem using css, but in body of the content I can't do it because **it is collaboration of two language fonts used in the site**.

So the fonts are not looking good in English.

Is there any JavaScript, CSS or any other method to set different font family based on text language?

**My need is**

**If the text is Tamil font then set Nova Sans Tamil

If the text is English font then set Roboto**

(Note): I can't use different classes for English font, so don't give this solution. Because I am using English font in thousands of places, it is very hard to change.

Comment: You can't style text based on language. You need to identify that text with a unique class of some kind which can be used for CSS.

Comment: So class is the only solution? @JacobPeattie

Comment: I agree with Jacob, CSS alone (without a class or id) can't do this for you. What plugin are you using for the translations, WPML?Then i can give you a solution. But we need something else then pure css to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

This question is not about WordPress but about css. Actually there even is a straightforward solution, because css-3 has an attribute called [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range), which allows you to load fonts based on the character set. For [Tamil the unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_(Unicode_block)) is U+0B02..U+0BCD. So, if you have the english font as a standard you can easily change the font to Tamil whenever appropriate like this:

```
@font-face {   
  font-family: 'NovaSansTamil';
  src: url('novasanstamil.woff') format('woff'); /* full url to font needed */
  unicode-range: U+0B02-CD;
  }
```

Beware that [browser support is not yet universal](https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range) for this feature.

Comment: Quite well supported nowadays!

Answer (score 1):

Whichever solution you use for language switching, I am sure it sets a meta tag with the language (see case 1) or adds a class to the html or body tag (see case 2).

**Case 1**

If you have a meta or any other identifiable tag that holds the language value, but it is not a wrapper for your content, simply add a javascript code that watches for changes on that tag and simply add a class to the body based on what value the meta or whichever tag has.

Example based on meta tag:

`<meta name="language" content="english">`

JS Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    let newLang = jQuery('meta[name="language"]').attr('content');
    jQuery('body').removeClass('otherlanguage english').addClass(newLang); \\i am removing both language classes to make sure they are not added twice
});
```

Now check case 2 because that step comes next.

**Case 2**

Then in your CSS simply target

```
body.english p {
    font-family: whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anybody runs across this question in the future the easiest method (that I have found) is to simply grab your text elements, use regex to identify the character set and then add the element class as necessary.

```
var textElements = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
for (var i = 0; i < textElements.length; i++) {
    if (textElements[i].innerHTML.match(/[\u0B80-\u0BFF]/)) {
        textElements[i].className += " tamil";
    }
}
```

```
.content {
    font-family: "Nova Sans";
}
.tamil {
    font-family: whatever;
}
```

http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block (Choose the block range relevant to your lang).